# Python requests сайт возвращает ответ 'вы не авторизованы'

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()

url = 'https://es.ciur.ru/auth/login'


header = {
     'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',         
        }

data = {
    'login_login': 'ТУТ_ЛОГИГН',
    'login_password': 'ТУТ_ПАРОЛЬ',
    'login_next':'/'
    }

response = session.post(url, data=data, json = data, headers=header)


homework_url = "https://es.ciur.ru/api/HomeworkService/GetHomeworkFromRange"
responce = session.get(homework_url).json()

print(responce)
```

Хочу сделать парсер домашнего задания

Сайт возвращает ответ:

{'faultcode': 'Server', 'faultstring': 'Вы не авторизованы!', 'detail': ''}

Хотя запрос авторизации возвращает:

{"success": true, "redirect": "/"}

Сайт динамический, ссылка была взята из подгружаемого запроса с домашним заданием.

Comment: После запроса на авторизацию вы должны получить некий токен, который следует передавать в последующих запросах (например, как HTTP Header).

Comment: А почему Вы думаете, что по этому URL есть <forrm> ? Если перед Вашим post-запросом поставить обычный get-запрос, то вернётся вот такая строка:{"success": false, "redirect": "", "message": "\u041d\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0440\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u043b\u043e\u0433\u0438\u043d \u0438\u043b\u0438 \u043f\u0430\u0440\u043e\u043b\u044c."} Т.е. запрос неудачен по причине "Неверный логин или пароль."  Я предполагаю, что  надо действовать как-то иначе. Сначала надо прочитать страничку с тегом <form>, затем выбрать оттуда атрибут action и уже по URL из этого атрибута отправить POST.